# sed replace in AQL file

Tags: unix, sed

I currently have the aql file below and am trying to replace `dummy` with another value on the fly. I've tried various sed replacements, for example `sed -i '/s/dummy/real/g' filename2.aql` but keep hitting the following issues:

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
line 1: `items.find('
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

```
items.find(
     {
          "repo":"libs-release-local",
          "$and": [
            {
              "path": { "$match": "dummy"}
            }
          ]
     }
)
.sort({ "$asc": ["modified"] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `/` before `s`

```
sed -i '' 's/dummy/real/g' file
```

Comment: I tried that and i'm getting this:
`sed: 1: "filename.aql": invalid command code f`

Comment: @Mosinel: You're probably on MAC or a BSD system which requires a mandatory option with `-i`. This is required to give a suffix in order to create a backup file for eg ".bak".  By stating it as blank we're getting rid of backup option. If you really want a backup file then go for `sed -i.bak 's/dummy/real/g' file`

Comment: @Mosinel: Welcome :)